# How to get ref from custom component in react hook?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, ref

I have this code, using React.useRef() but not working:
Main.js:

```
import * as React from "react"
export const Main: React.FunctionComponent<Props> = observer((props) => {
  const ref = React.useRef()

  React.useEffect(() => {
    ///Can not get ref from message
    ref.gotoPosition(5)
  }, [])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Message
        ref={ref}
        getGotoIndex={getFunction}
        onEndList={isShowQuickMove}
        isSpeaker={state.isSpeaker}
        questionsList={state.questionsList}
        clickQuestion={clickQuestion}
        isTyping={chatStore.loading}
        data={state.data}/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

Message.js:

```
import * as React from "react"
// eslint-disable-next-line react/display-name
export const Message = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => ({
  const { ... } = props

  const gotoPosition = (index) => {
    console.log('in here')
  }
  return (
    <View>
....
</View>
  )
}
)
```

I can not get ref from Message, even i used React.forwardRef. How to access gotoPosition function in Message by ref like ref.gotoPosition(5). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the ref you get to the `Flatlist` all you need to do is pass it like so:

```
    <FlatList
      ref={ref} // create a referenece like so
      extraData={[data, isSpeaker]}
      onEndReached={handleEnd}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.4}
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      renderItem={renderItems}
    />
```

Comment: Hi, but it not my expect, i was edit my question, please see again, thanks